# Как подсчитать сумму в столбце в таблице. Версия PHP: 7.1.30

Tags: php

Помогите, пожалуйста. Я пока не разбираюсь в php. Как подсчитать сумму в столбце boardsSold в таблице boards. Попробовала следующий код

```php
       <?php
           $res = $connect->query("SELECT SUM(`boardsSold`) FROM `boards`");
           if (FALSE === $res) die("Select sum failed: ".mysqli_error);
           $row = mysqli_fetch_row($res);
           $sum = $row[0];
       ?>
```

он выдает ошибку

```
Connected successfully
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in /var/www/u1353398/data/www/en777.ru/databaseconnect.php:14 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/u1353398/data/www/en777.ru/databaseconnect.php on line 14
```

Comment: Во-первых, что такое `$connect`? Во-вторых, почему так получилось, что оно имеет значение `null`?

Comment: Большое спасибо за подсказку. Заработало